# Python: binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string

Tags: python-3.x, base64, decoding, binascii

I am processing the email files from Amazon SES. The email contains a pdf file encoded with base64.

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="IN081AKC.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="IN081AKC.pdf"
```

encoded_string = “JVBERi0xLjI……………….”

I am trying to decode the string with base64.b64decode(encoded_string) but getting
the exception

```
   return base64.b64decode(encoded_string)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (12693) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
```

I checked the padding also,
len(encoded_string)%4 = 0

The encoded_string ends with `"A==="`.
If I remove `"A==="` or add `"A=="` then I am able to decode the string.
Can we remove `"A==="` from the end of the string?

Comment: The string ends with A===. If I remove A=== then I am able to decode it. But I am sure if this is the right thing to do.

Comment: If I remove A===, then the decoded string ends with "91\r\n%%EOF\r\n".  And if I add A== then the decoded string ends with "91\r\n%%EOF\r\n\x00'". Is it safe to remove A===?